# Time for k events given a time upper limit

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-process

If we have a Poisson-process with rate $\lambda$, the time it takes for $k$ events to happen is the sum of $k$ exponentially distributed RVs.

Now consider some interval $[x, x+\hat{t}$]. Let $T_i$ be the time the i-th event (in that interval) occurs and $N$ the number of events in that interval.

How to find $Pr(T_k < t | N \geq k)$?

**What I did so far:**

Calculated the number of events:

$i\geq k: Pr(N = i | i \geq k) = \frac{P_\lambda(k)}{\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} P_\lambda(i)} = \frac{P_\lambda(k)}{1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} P_\lambda(k)}$ where $P_\lambda$ is the Poisson-distribution
$i < k:  Pr(N = i | i \geq k) = 0$

I tried to find $Pr(T_k < t | N \geq k)$ but I don't know how to properly include the time upper-limit $\hat{t}$. I also tried finding a recursive relationship, calculating $Pr(T_k  < t | N \geq k)$ using $Pr(T_{k-1} < t | N \geq k-1)$.

Comment: A possible approach (though I don't see that it would yield a solution in closed form): Conditional on $N=n$, the $n$ events are uniformly distributed in the interval. Thus $\mathsf P(T_k\lt t\mid N=n)$ is the probability that the $k$-th order statistic of $n$ uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ is less than $t/\hat t$. That's a beta distribution (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Order_statistics)). Then you can sum over $n$ with your probabilities.

Comment: @joriki Since I don't need a closed solution, this works for me. If you want to make this an answer, I will accept it.